# How do I create a Partial Index with an $in in the filter expression?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm basically trying to create a unique partial filter in my collection with a filter that I know works, but MongoDB doesn't accept it.

Here is my statement:

```js
db.payments.createIndex(
  {
      "userId": 1,
      "accountId": 1,
      "status": 1
  },
  {
      unique: true,
      partialFilterExpression: {
          status: { 
              $in: ["new", "paid", "excluded"]
          }
      }
)
```

And I get this error message:

> 2021-04-20 18:53:42] com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 67 (CannotCreateIndex): 'Error in specification { key: { userId: 1, accountId: 1, status: 1 }, name: "userId_1_accountId_1_status_1", unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { status: { $in: [ "new", "paid", "excluded" ] } }, v: 2 } :: caused by :: unsupported expression in partial index: status $in [ "new" "paid" "excluded" ]

If I try to filter it by a single status it works, *e.g.*

```js
{
    partialFilterExpression: {
        status: { 
            $eq: "new" 
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I want to have multiple statuses allowed on the index it doesn't work. I couldn't find anything in the documentation stating that an `$in` expression is not supported. So how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$in` is not allowed in a partial filter expression.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#create-a-partial-index):

> The partialFilterExpression option accepts a document that specifies the filter condition using:
>
> - equality expressions (i.e. field: value or using the $eq operator),
> - $exists: true expression,
> - $gt, $gte, $lt, $lte expressions,
> - $type expressions,
> - $and operator at the top-level only

Comment: Starting with MongoDB v6.0 the `$in` operator is supported along with `$or`